# How to view class package type and parameters in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When hovering your mouse over a Class or variable, how come I don't see any information on the  type of the class?

Is this not a feature in IntelliJ?

For example, in vs.net, if I mouse over any variable or class it will popup and tell me what namespace that belongs to etc.

And when I am using a method of a class, it also tells me the different overloads for the method (like types for each parameter, and a list of all the overloads).

This must be a feature in IntelliJ, I just don't know how to get it.

Can someone please clear this up?

Also, how can I tidy up the formatting of a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting: `Code -> Reformat` (shortcut: `Ctrl-Alt-L`)

Hover doesn't produce the kind of information I'd like either. You can get info with `Ctrl-Q` ("Quick Help") in Windows or `F1` in OS X, which will show where it's from and what it is, with most stuff in the popup window linked up in a reasonable way.

That popup view can also be pinned and/or docked; I often have it docked on the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work on hover yet, please [star/vote the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5999).

You need to use keyboard shortcuts for **quick documentation** pop-up or **parameter info** pop-up (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with default Windows keymap, <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with default OS X 10.5+ keymap).

`Code` | `Reformat Code...` is the answer to your second question.

Comment: Help | Find Action, type the action name, see the shortcut from your keymap displayed next to it.